# CSS: .table-responsive class messes up tooltip's content [fiddle provided]

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I've got this problem - after adding `.table-responsive` class the table header tooltips got lost `overflow-x: auto` - Setting it off makes it alright but disables the responsivness of the table.

I've created code snippet to show you

*https://jsfiddle.net/kristjanrei/74aa8x6u/*

Default code for tooltip

```
.container {
  padding: 200px;
}
.custom-tooltip-hover {
    position: relative;
}

.custom-tooltip { /* hide and position tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: initial;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 110;
    transition-delay: 0.33s;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: initial;
    word-break: inherit; 
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: normal;
}

.custom-tooltip.left {
    left: initial;
    right: 0px;
}

.custom-tooltip:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-top: 8px solid #000000;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.custom-tooltip.left:after {
    left: initial;
    right: 12%;
}

.custom-tooltip-hover:hover .custom-tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline;
    transition-delay: 0.88s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.88s; /* Safari */
}

.break-tooltip {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

A snippet from jsfiddle of a broken tooltip.
[image]

Way it works every where else

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the table-responsive class?

Comment: @AaronUllal Using the bootstrap's table responsive

Comment: Do not circumvent the "links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" rule.  We have this rule for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

I have added this on the div panel and it has worked `style="overflow:visible;`

```css
.container {
  padding: 200px;
}
.custom-tooltip-hover {
    position: relative;
}

.custom-tooltip { /* hide and position tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: initial;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 11000000;
    transition-delay: 0.33s;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: initial;
    word-break: inherit; 
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: normal;
}

.custom-tooltip.left {
    left: initial;
    right: 0px;
}

.custom-tooltip:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-top: 8px solid #000000;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.custom-tooltip.left:after {
    left: initial;
    right: 12%;
}

.custom-tooltip-hover:hover .custom-tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline;
    transition-delay: 0.88s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.88s; /* Safari */
}

.break-tooltip {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-tooltip-hover">
    <div>
      Working header
    </div>

    <span class="custom-tooltip">
      Tooltip for head
    </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive"  style="overflow:visible;">
      <table class="table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> 
                  <div class="custom-tooltip-hover">
                      <div>
                       Broken Header
                      </div>

                      <span class="custom-tooltip">
                        Tooltip for head
                      </span>
                   </div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td> Content for head</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need the resposivness. width 100% aint gonna do anything.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold what about now? I have added the table-responsive on the table instead as on the div?

Comment: It has to be in the wrapper. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: @kristjanreinhold you dont have to limiting yourself. explore everything. Bootstrap just provides defaults. but to make things work the way you want, you will have to explore. The best way to force it to work the way you want is to apply the css directly on the div or table to make it responsive

Comment: You havent providden anything working yet.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold now i got you i had had not understood your question correctly. I have edited my answer. try to see if it works

Comment: This does work however table responsivess is broken =(

Comment: You could try adding more content to see how it responds =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide some part of content with overflow, then you are able to use position:fixed for the .custom-tooltip class and place it with js.

Checkout the library [tether](http://github.hubspot.com/tether/) (bootstrap also use it for tooltips), there are a lot of options, to attache the element to another element. I think it'll be much easier.

Comment: Nah, our solution is all over the project already, choosing a new library for that is a no go. And it works everywhere but here.

Comment: Two properties that broke your tooltip:
    overflow-x: auto on .table-responsive